# Need help producing triangular waveforms

Tags: waveform, pspice

I've recently started using pspice and just created my circuit but don't understand how to do step 3 on procedures. I've created my circuit based on the second picture shown below (ignore my 10V). I've also made sure to show the waveforms I got by following all procedures except for step 3. I just don't understand how to do step 3.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Part 3 is  just asking you to set the parameters for the simulators Vin source to generate the required triangular waveform. You don't have to build a circuit for it. I know nothing about pSpice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct selection possible for a triangular signal voltage source.

Set the properties of the Voltage source as follows

1. Choose a VPULSE source as usual
2. Set the `Tr` rise time to about 0.49 times the period of the signal
3. Set the `Tf` fall time to the same value as the rise
4. The `PW` pulse width can be very small ideally can be set to 0.01 times the period.
5. Below figure is generic VPULSE waveform. Modifying the timings will change it to triangular wave

   [image]

You can slightly change or tweak the values. Let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, step 4a indicates the voltage source is a "piecewise linear" part (VPWL). That part lets you specify voltage versus time value pairs. From the example:

```
DC=0; AC=0; T1=0ms; V1=0V; T2=0.25mS; V2=0.4V; T3=0.75ms; V3=-0.4V; T4=1ms; V4=0V

N  Time (s)   Voltage (V)
-  --------   -----------
1   0m           0
2   0.25m        0.4
3   0.75m       -0.4
4   1m           0
```

If you plot these voltage vs. time values on a piece of graph paper you'll discover they plot out one cycle of a triangle wave whose peak amplitudes are ± 0.4 V and whose period is 1 ms.

IIRC, PSpice uses the token "DC=0;" for parametric sweep simulations (and perhaps to perform the DC bias point calculation when a transient analysis is defined and its start time is not zero seconds), and the token "AC=0;" is used with AC sweep simulations.

Comment: That makes it a lot clearer thank you.